# Strange execution errors in application

Tags: c++, debugging, boost-test

I've got a unit test I'm writing which seems to have some kind of a pointer problem. Basically, it's testing a class that, once constructed, returns information about a file. If all the files expected are detected, then the test operates correctly. If there are more files expected than detected, then the routine correctly reports error. But if there are more files detected than expected, the executable crashes. This has been difficult to follow because when I try to step through with the debugger, the current code point jumps all over the method -- it doesn't follow line by line like you'd expect.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing incorrectly?

Here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "boostUnitTest.h"

#include "../pevFind/fileData.h" //Header file for tested code.
#include "../pevFind/stringUtil.h" //convertUnicode()

struct fileDataLoadingFixture
{
    std::vector<fileData> testSuiteCandidates;
    fileDataLoadingFixture()
    {
        WIN32_FIND_DATA curFileData;
        HANDLE fData = FindFirstFile(L"testFiles\\*", &curFileData);
        if (fData == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to load file list!");
        do {
            if(boost::algorithm::equals(curFileData.cFileName, L".")) continue;
            if(boost::algorithm::equals(curFileData.cFileName, L"..")) continue;
            fileData theFile(curFileData, L".\\testFiles\\");
            testSuiteCandidates.push_back(theFile);
        } while (FindNextFile(fData, &curFileData));
        FindClose(fData);
    };
};

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE( fileDataTests, fileDataLoadingFixture )

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( testPEData )
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> expectedResults;
    expectedResults.push_back(L"a.cfexe");
    expectedResults.push_back(L"b.cfexe");
    //More files.... 
    expectedResults.push_back(L"c.cfexe");
    std::sort(expectedResults.begin(), expectedResults.end());
    for (std::vector<fileData>::const_iterator it = testSuiteCandidates.begin(); it != testSuiteCandidates.end(); it++)
    {
        if (it->isPE())
        {
            std::wstring theFileString(it->getFileName().substr(it->getFileName().find_last_of(L'\\') + 1 ));
            std::vector<std::wstring>::const_iterator target = std::lower_bound(expectedResults.begin(), expectedResults.end(), theFileString);
            BOOST_REQUIRE_MESSAGE(*target == theFileString, std::string("The file ") + convertUnicode(theFileString) + " was unexpected." );
            if (*target == theFileString)
            {
                expectedResults.erase(target);
            }
        }
    }
    BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE(expectedResults.size() == 0, "Some expected results were not found." );
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Thanks!

Billy3

I solved the problem using the following code instead:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( testPEData )
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> expectedResults;
    expectedResults.push_back(L"blah.cfexe");
    //files
    expectedResults.push_back(L"tail.cfexe");
    expectedResults.push_back(L"zip.cfexe");
    std::vector<std::wstring> actualResults;
    for(std::vector<fileData>::const_iterator it = testSuiteCandidates.begin(); it != testSuiteCandidates.end(); it++)
    {
        if (it->isPE()) actualResults.push_back(it->getFileName().substr(it->getFileName().find_last_of(L'\\') + 1 ));
    }

    std::sort(expectedResults.begin(), expectedResults.end());
    std::sort(actualResults.begin(), actualResults.end());

    std::vector<std::wstring> missed;
    std::set_difference(expectedResults.begin(), expectedResults.end(), actualResults.begin(), actualResults.end(), std::back_inserter(missed));

    std::vector<std::wstring> incorrect;
    std::set_difference(actualResults.begin(), actualResults.end(), expectedResults.begin(), expectedResults.end(), std::back_inserter(incorrect));

    for(std::vector<std::wstring>::const_iterator it = missed.begin(); it != missed.end(); it++)
    {
        BOOST_ERROR(std::string("The file ") + convertUnicode(*it) + " was expected but not returned.");
    }

    for(std::vector<std::wstring>::const_iterator it = incorrect.begin(); it != incorrect.end(); it++)
    {
        BOOST_ERROR(std::string("The file ") + convertUnicode(*it) + " was returned but not expected.");
    }

    BOOST_CHECK(true); //Suppress commandline "No assertions" warning

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think this will return, in the event that the file was unexpected? It looks like you expect it to be a valid file name.

```
std::vector<std::wstring>::const_iterator target = std::lower_bound(expectedResults.begin(), expectedResults.end(), theFileString);
```

It will in fact be an iterator at one past the end of the array - you cannot treat it as a valid pointer:

```
BOOST_REQUIRE_MESSAGE(*target == theFileString, std::string("The file ") + convertUnicode(theFileString) + " was unexpected." );
```

Normall, you compare the result with the value of `end()` (fixed):

```
BOOST_REQUIRE_MESSAGE(target != expectedResults.end() || *target == theFileString, std::string("The file ") + convertUnicode(theFileString) + " was unexpected." );
if (target != expectedResults.end() && *target == theFileString)
{
  expectedResults.erase(target);
}
```

See in [this example here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/lower_bound.html), `lower_bound` will return off-then-end values:

```
int main()
{
  int A[] = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 8 };
  const int N = sizeof(A) / sizeof(int);

  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
    int* p = lower_bound(A, A + N, i);
    cout << "Searching for " << i << ".  ";
    cout << "Result: index = " << p - A << ", ";
    if (p != A + N)
      cout << "A[" << p - A << "] == " << *p << endl;
    else
      cout << "which is off-the-end." << endl;
  }
}

The output is:

Searching for 1.  Result: index = 0, A[0] == 1
Searching for 2.  Result: index = 1, A[1] == 2
Searching for 3.  Result: index = 2, A[2] == 3
Searching for 4.  Result: index = 5, A[5] == 5
Searching for 5.  Result: index = 5, A[5] == 5
Searching for 6.  Result: index = 6, A[6] == 8
Searching for 7.  Result: index = 6, A[6] == 8
Searching for 8.  Result: index = 6, A[6] == 8
Searching for 9.  Result: index = 7, which is off-the-end.
Searching for 10.  Result: index = 7, which is off-the-end.
```

You cannot safely dereference the off-the-end value, but you can use it for the purpose of comparison, or as an insertion point.

Why are you using `lower_bound` anyway? For the purposes of search, surely you should use `find`? If you are using `lower_bound`, it will return a position where the file name *could* be inserted, but not necessarily equal to the file name you are looking for. In other words, you not only need to compare with the off-the-end value, but also with the file name, in case it returned something valid.

Here is a version that uses `find`. As you can see it is simpler than the fixed version above.

```
std::vector<std::wstring>::const_iterator target = std::find(expectedResults.begin(), expectedResults.end(), theFileString);
BOOST_REQUIRE_MESSAGE(target != expectedResults.end(), std::string("The file ") + convertUnicode(theFileString) + " was unexpected." );
if (target != expectedResults.end())
{
  expectedResults.erase(target);
}
```

Comment: From SGI's docs on std::lower_bound:  
    Specifically, it returns the first position where value could be inserted without violating the ordering.  
from http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/lower_bound.html  
Indicates that the iterator returned should be valid even if the item is not found. std::find returns end on failure... I don't believe lower_bound does.

Comment: Oh, and editing the code as you suggest causes the test in question to produce incorrect results.

Comment: On the page you linked to, there is a specific example which shows it will return an off-the-end value

Comment: @Billy: insert functions in the STL insert *before* the position iterator. Therefore, when the searched element is greater than all elements in the range, lower_bound returns an end iterator, which you must not dereference (although you can for example pass it to vector::insert)

Comment: I fixed the code suggestion, although, do you think you should be using find instead of lower_bound? It would make the code simpler

Comment: Lower_Bound is an O(lg n) operation, whereas find is O(n). This is why I did it that way.. I guess I'll just do this differently. Thanks for pointing out the bug though. Checkmarking due to pointing out that bug, even if it didn't actually solve the problem.

Comment: If you are concerned about the runtime, maybe you should use a map? A better data structure can optimise performance too

Comment: See the code I posted above that fixed the problem :) Thanks! Should spend more time in STL manuals :P

Comment: @1800: I wouldn't expect a map to be any faster for searching than an ordered vector with lower_bound. About log(N) comparisons either way, although the map might be somewhat unbalanced whereas a binary search never is. Am I missing something? Map is faster for insertion and deletion at the middle, of course.

Answer (score 0):

> "the current code point jumps all over
>   the method -- it doesn't follow line
>   by line like you'd expect"

This usually means you have more than 1 thread hitting the method at a time.  I usually see this when more than 1 object on my aspx page causes a postback at the same time.

Comment: I guess you are debugging an optimised build - debugging those tends to be more difficult

Comment: Nope. Debug build. No reason to build a release build for unit tests ;)

Comment: No I don't see any threads, but then again you wouldn't see any in the example I gave either.  There is more than 1 thread when 2 items cause a postback.

Answer (score 0):

"the current code point jumps all over the method -- it doesn't follow line by line like you'd expect"

Check your compiler options! Have you got debug on and optimise off?

Optimising compilers often completly "rewrite" your code changing the order of instructions,
unrolling loops etc. etc. so that the debugger has difficulty in mapping an executable instruction to the original line of code.

Comment: It's running in debug mode :(